# Using OR operator with 2 placeholders with same value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a newcomer to Android Programming and looking for some help with my query. I am trying to find all fixtures where the `id` of a selected team is equal to the home team `team_1_id` or away team `team_2_id`

I have the below query, it is only returning results where the `id` is `team_1_id` and not `team_2_id`

```
public List < Fixture > getTeamFixtures(int id) {
 List < Fixture > fixtureList = new ArrayList < Fixture > ();

 // Select All Query
 String selectQuery = "
SELECT fixtures.id, 
       fixtures.team_1_id, 
       fixtures.team_2_id, 
       fixtures.date, 
       fixtures.time, 
       fixtures.pitch, 
       teams.team_name, 
       teams_1.team_name AS awayTeam, 
       leagues.league_name, 
       leagues.id 
FROM   fixtures 
       INNER JOIN teams 
               ON fixtures.team_1_id = teams.id 
       INNER JOIN teams AS teams_1 
               ON fixtures.team_2_id = teams_1.id 
       INNER JOIN teams_vs_leagues 
               ON teams.id = teams_vs_leagues.team_id 
       INNER JOIN leagues 
               ON teams_vs_leagues.league_id = leagues.id 
WHERE  fixtures.team_1_id = ? 
        OR fixtures.team_2_id = ? 
";

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {
  String.valueOf(id)
 });
 // looping through all rows and adding to list
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
   Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
   fixture.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
   fixture.setTeamId1(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
   fixture.setTeamId2(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
   fixture.setDate(cursor.getString(3));
   fixture.setTime(cursor.getString(4));
   fixture.setPitch(cursor.getString(5));
   fixture.setTeamName1(cursor.getString(6));
   fixture.setTeamName2(cursor.getString(7));
   fixture.setLeagueName(cursor.getString(8));
   fixture.setLeagueId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));
   // Adding team to list
   fixtureList.add(fixture);
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
 // close inserting data from database
 db.close();
 // return fixturelist
 return fixtureList;

}
```

Whenever I try

```
WHERE fixtures.team_1_id = ?
```

OR

```
WHERE fixtures.team_2_id = ?
```

The query returns the relevant results but I want to be able to see whether the `id` appears in either `team_1_id` or `team_2_id`

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: just put your value twice in the param list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam), you can reuse a parameter by giving it an explicit number:

```
... WHERE fixtures.team_1_id = ?1 OR fixtures.team_2_id = ?1 ...
```

or by giving it a name:

```
... WHERE fixtures.team_1_id = :TeamID OR fixtures.team_2_id = :TeamID ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea how to reuse a parameter. That really helped, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in`:

```
WHERE ? in (fixtures.team_1_id, fixtures.team_2_id)
```

Comment: I had tried this method but it is still not returning any results.

Comment: so take out the where clause and see what is being returned.

Comment: I need the value of the placeholder to pass in the ArrayList I am using. Although I use the same query in another method minus the WHERE clause and it returns all Fixtures

Comment: When I try `WHERE (fixtures.team_1_id = ?) OR (fixtures.team_2_id = ?)` It will only return fixtures where the id passed is the `team_1_id` so if they are they away team i.e `team_2_id` they do not appear. Any idea why this may be the case. I checked in the listview the the team_2_id displays correctly.